# How can I automate Lightroom to use a sequence of presets on a sequence of images?

Tags: lightroom, automation, presets, plugin

I work for a used car dealership. We take 60-65 photos for each vehicle, bring them to Lightroom to color grade, crop, and straighten. This process takes about 10-15 minutes per truck and requires a person to be sitting at a computer and work through the process. There is little variation between vehicles. Our photos are shot in the same order every time, in a light-controlled room to avoid differences in color and amount of light.

I would like to automate the process of applying the presets we have to each image.
Exterior photos receive a different preset than interior photos, red vehicles get different presets than black ones, etc.
I have 3 presets for exterior images, one for interior, and would eventually like to make a preset for each angle individually.

Is there a way, most likely thought a Lightroom plugin, that will pull the images in order and apply the presets in sequence?

```
The 1st image in the selection ---> preset for angle 1
The 2nd image in the selection ---> preset for angle 2
The 3rd image in the selection ---> preset for angle 3
and so on...
```

I looked through other forums hoping other people have asked this question before, and to my misfortune have not found anything similar to what I am looking for.

Comment: the hard part on this process is not to automate that there are presets applied but that you want to choose different presets depending on the image. this image analysis is not as easy done as you think and requires some good computer vision knowledge.

Comment: @LuZel given OP stated the same set of photos is taken for every vehicle, it won't be necessary to implement image analysis if the images are always in the same order

Comment: but then if you have enough power u could export the images with all the presets for this kind and remove the bad ones from hand. then it would be semi automatic. this could help a bit

Comment: also why only in lightroom. i know the automation in photoshop works quite well and can do all the things LR can do and its easy to create this automation.

Comment: @LuZel I also think Photoshop actions should be able to this. It is possible to ["transfer"](https://photoshopcafe.com/use-lightroom-presets-photoshop/) presets from Lightroom to Photoshop to be used in Adobe Camera Raw. But perhaps the OP does not have access to Photoshop?

Comment: If you can switch to Rawtherapee, it offers a CLI tool. It is possible to write (or ask somebody to write) a tool that takes a sequence of DNGs and a sequence of .pp3 files (Rawtherapee profile format) and applies each profile to each raw. I find Rawtherapee is at least equivalent or more powerful than Lightroom, but UI is less polished.

Answer (score 1):

In LR you could identify the images you want a given preset applied to... i.e. select all of the images with a red truck and give them the red color label. And create a smart collection that pulls all of the images where the label color = red; plus any additional rule you see fitting. Then select the smart collection and apply your preset to all of the images within it.

The smart collection only has to be created once, and you would need to set one up for each preset. The smart collection is also "virtual;" the files remain in their original file structure/organizational locations.

[image]

I think the requirement to sequence through different edits (presets) as it steps through a sequence of different images is too much for any basic batch edit/action type function.